# Can't disable ForwardReceivedMessagesTo in NServiceBus 4

Tags: azure, nservicebus

I have an endpoint hosted in an azure worker role that is entirely configured with code and i can't turn off the ForwarReceivedMessagesTo feature. The default "audit" queue keeps getting created and all messages are forwarded even though i do not have this feature specified.

What am i missing here?

Below is the UnicastBusConfig configuration override i am using:

```
 /// <summary>
/// Configuration for Routing the Messaging
/// </summary>
internal class EndpointRoutingConfiguration : IProvideConfiguration<UnicastBusConfig>
{
    public UnicastBusConfig GetConfiguration()
    {
        return new UnicastBusConfig
        {
            MessageEndpointMappings = new MessageEndpointMappingCollection
            {
                new MessageEndpointMapping
                    {
                        Messages = MESSAGES_ASSEMBLY_NAME,
                        Endpoint = SERVER_QUEUE_NAME                      
                    }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so i finally figured out that this only happens locally. When deployed to azure the messages are not forwarded to the audit queue as specified in the configuration.